# How to decrypt encrypted image in memory & use in Application

Tags: c#, wpf, encryption

I am working on a WPF application which is using resources (Images, video's etc. ) from folder ,**I am encrypting all the resources by given encryption mechanism**  .

Now  when i am using resources by applying **decryption technique given bellow** , here I need to save the file on some place in local drive & use in application , I don't want it because when file is decrypted user can see the file & change it .

**Is it possible to decrypt the file** like **Images** in **memory & use it in the application without** saving the file in memory.

```
public class EncryptFile_DecryptFile   
{   
   #region Encrypt Images & save it  
   public string EncryptFile(Image img,string ImagePath_to_Save)  
    {          
       byte[] ImageBytes;
        ImageBytes = imageToByteArray(img);   

            for (int i = 0; i < ImageBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                ImageBytes[i] = (byte)(ImageBytes[i] ^ 5);
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(ImagePath_to_Save, ImageBytes);
     return ImagePath_to_Save;
    }
   #endregion
   #region Convert Image in to Byte
   public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
    #endregion


   #region Decrypt Image & save it
   public string DecryptFile(string ImagePath_to_Save)
    {
             byte[] ImageBytes;

            ImageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ImagePath_to_Save);

            for (int i = 0; i < ImageBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                ImageBytes[i] = (byte)(ImageBytes[i] ^ 5);
            }

            File.WriteAllBytes(ImagePath_to_Save, ImageBytes);
             return ImagePath_to_Save;

    }
   #endregion
}
```

Otherwise please suggest me some alternate way to use the encrypted resources in application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) instead of a FileStream. This will keep your image in memory.

Here is how you can implement it.

```
public Stream DecryptFile(string encryptedImageFile){
  byte[] ImageBytes;

  ImageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(encryptedImageFile);

  for (int i = 0; i < ImageBytes.Length; i++){
    ImageBytes[i] = (byte)(ImageBytes[i] ^ 5);
  }

  return new MemoryStream(ImageBytes);
}
```